# Change selected value in WTF form selected field from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, flask-wtforms

I have three WTF form selected field on my webpage and they are dependent - i.e. 1st selected field is country, 2nd is state and third is city. So far I have managed to make them dependable and thus if you choose the US it will only show states in the US etc.

However, once the user selects a country, I would like to set the default value of the state to the largest state in the US, and then the largest city in that state.

Somehow I have not been able to find any documentation on how you can set the current value of a WTF form selected field from JS.

So the question is: I don't know how to access the field and change the value.

```
//the country_w_states is a dict with the countries as keys and states as lists (parsed from server) 

//triggered when user selects a country
$(".country-changed").change(function(){
update_state()
});

//update associated states
function update_state() {
    var country = $('#selected_country').val()
    
    var country_w_states = {{ country_w_states|tojson}};
    $('#selected_state').empty();
    country_w_states[country].forEach(function(item) {
            $('#selected_state').append(
                $('<option>', {
                    text: item
                })
            );
        });
    //How to set the selected/default value of the state field?
    //Something like the below...
    //$('#selected_state').default() = largest_city[country] 


    update_city() //update city based on state - same methodology as above (omitted since not really relevant for question)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out after several hours.
It is possible to set a "selected" flag to true when you append an option.

So for the one option you wish to have selected, set selected: true

```
$('<option>', {
                value: item,
                text: item,
                selected: true
            })
```